# Skype companywide global contacts list

Tags: voip, skype, contacts

We are a medium sized company based across several sites and with a number of home workers.  We have more or less settled on Skype as our defacto method of communication.  At the moment the only pain is ensuring that everybody has all the other employees added to their contact list.  Can be a real pain when a new employee starts and they have to send details to everyone else and vice versa.

Is there a solution that allows us to manage a central contacts list that we can push out to new/existing users?

Answer (score 1):

Skype offers the ability to import contacts (look under contacts), as well as exporting them (look under contacts->advanced).